# Please make the data SE to handle the logins so smartly as the other sites do

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

If I log in into the data SE, it always forgets my login credentials. I have to log in again and again.

I think, the feature is available in the other SE sites, and maybe it wouldn't be very hard to import it into the data SE code as well.

Answer (score 5):

This may happen some day, but not without a tremendous amount of thought and likely time. The problem is that Data Explorer is open source (https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer), which means we can't just plug in our authentication pieces. It's quite complicated, and from the SEDE point of view: a lot of baggage for anyone *not us*.

Maybe one day. Since we're now using cookies for auth up on the second level domains (to prep for the child `meta.*` moves long ago), it's at least closer to possible.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't see any trace that it would have access to the data SE SQL port. Although it could make possible for the community to create pull requests from that.

Comment: @peterh I honestly don't know what you're talking about, what's "the data SE SQL port"?

Comment: I tried to explain that it is an SQL data management tool, but downloading & compiling & deploying it doesn't mean also access to the stackexchange databases. To do that, they should be mirrored first.

Comment: Still not sure I'm following, but under no circumstances would I ever give it access to our databases :) At best, it'd be an API call based on the header cookie defined in config that did a lookup to get the account...but that'd tie heavily to our APIs, so it'd have to be generic and...anyway, yeah - this would require API design on both sides.

Comment: More likely, we'd give SEDE SAML (or similar) capabilities, and try to do that as transparently as possible for the user, so that it'd be generally usable to anyone in a SSO environment.

Comment: As far I know, behind the data SE is a read-only mirror of the databases, obviously on security reasons. To this DB, having an open TCP port, wouldn't be a serious security risk (compared to the currently available interface to the data SE).

Comment: The DB access isn't the issue, it's the login, answering the basic question of "who is this user?" - that's completely different in SEDE, and totally disconnected. We'd have to integrate it with the system that knows which account/user your cookie is.

Comment: Isn't there still the issue that the session cookie expires way more frequently than intended? I forget what the problem was there